# How do you determine the exception being thrown by MkDir?

Tags: freepascal, mkdir

I am using [Mkdir](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/mkdir.html) from the Free Pascal [System](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/) unit.

If a directory already exists with the same name as is being passed to this procedure, an error occurs. With the [$IOCHECKS](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu38.html#x45-440001.2.38) compiler directive set to {$I-}, the program continues, but [IOResult](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/ioresult.html) is set to error code 5. Without the {$I-} compiler directive, an exception is thrown. If not caught, the program exits with return code of 5, reflecting the error.

I would like to catch this SPECIFIC exception, whatever it may be named. However, I don't know how to find the exact name of the exception raised.

Note: I have accepted the answer given, but there is one statement that I disagree with:

> Runtime error to exception conversion is a feature of sysutils.

In my testing, just adding a try/except/end section stops the standard runtime error program abort (with message to stdout). Instead program flow goes to the "except..end" block and continues on after that. However, without using the SysUtils unit you cannot determine which exception was raised since the exception classes are defined there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system unit has a rudimentary "terminate with errorcode" routine called runerror, which is what you see. It is not an exception.  That looks like this:

```
[D:\testing]blaat
Runtime error 5 at $00401437
  $00401437
  $00406E91
```

Other than preventing it with the ioresult method this is non-recoverable

Runtime error to exception conversion is a feature of sysutils. If you already USES sysutils, it raise EInOutError andlook like this:

```
[D:\testing]blaat
 An unhandled exception occurred at $00401557:
 EInOutError: Access denied
 $00401557
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking back at the documentation for MkDir it does say "runtime error" and doesn't mention an exception being thrown. However, if I put the MkDir call in a try/except block and just do a WriteLn in the except part, I see that message printed out, even without SysUtils in the program. Do try/except blocks also handle runtime errors?

Comment: No, but sysutils hooks the runtime error procedure and raises them as exception.

Comment: My code goes into the "except" section on MkDir failure,  even without "Uses SysUtils" being in the program. Maybe SysUtils is included automatically like System.

Comment: No. But probably it is somewhere included (either in your or in other units supplied with FPC/Lazarus). I tried with an empty program and just enabling mode delphi, and I get the runtime error.

Comment: I am not using Lazarus, just the command line. I have nothing in the single file program but $mode, try/except, writeln, and mkdir and I don't get a runtime error with either ObjFPC or Delphi modes.

Comment: So am I. Try to isolate it a minimal program first, and submit that to the bugtracker if need be.

Comment: It's not a bug to me. If I put try/except in a program I want runtime errors to become exceptions.

Comment: The only thing I could take out is "program" and the "writeln" statements, leaving begin..end, mkdir and try/except/end. I still do not get a runtime error.